# Switching plugin license from Craft 2 to Craft 3

Tags: craft3, plugins

Dumb question, but...

I purchased a plugin when using Craft 2 and now I'm trying to input the license for it in Craft 3. There's an input for the license key when I go to settings -> plugins, but the submit for it says "buy now" and tries to put the plugin in my cart. How do I give Craft 3 the license?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a question for the plugin developer. If the plugin isn't purchased through the plugin store, then each developer is responsible for generating Craft 3 licenses on their own.

It's probably safe to say that your Craft 2 license number is not going to match your Craft 3 license number. Contact the plugin's developer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I figured it out. My plugin's old license key wasn't long enough to satisfy the key input. This box is expecting a license in the exact format it shows - with 6 sets of 4 numbers (my old key only had 5 sets). Once you've input that many numbers the button changes.

I scoured my plugin's documentation and found that I need to request a Craft3 compatible key.